# Why can't I see my edit history anymore?

Tags: support, edits

Before the recent upgrade to SO, I remember being able to see my edit history (for questions and answers) and also other users edit history from the question/answer section itself.

Now I don't see it anymore there. Why was this taken off? It was very useful.

**Going to profile** and checking for revisions is not the same experience.

**Update:** Ok, so the thing that confused me is this:

- If I edited within a span of minute (or few maybe), I don't see the edit history link.
- Or does the edit history link appear after few minutes?

[image: Edited this post 2 times within a span of minutes or 2 maybe]

Comment: Looks the same to me. Not sure what upgrade you're talking about.

Comment: @Cody Gray: See my update. That led me to my OP.

Comment: You have a five-minute window in which edits you make don't count as a new revision.

Comment: @Tim Stone: Ahh, I see! Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per your question update, you'll only see the history link on the post when a second revision has been created. When you first write a post (and on subsequent separate edits), you have a five minute grace period in which you can continue to make changes without generating a new revision, so it's possible to edit a new post without having that link show up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the revisions made from you to the posts, I still see it.

[image: screenshot]

For seeing it from the post, simply click on the timestamp reported after "edited"; in the screenshot, "2 hours ago" is a link to the page that shows all the revisions.

[image: screenshot]

**Update**: There is a 5 minutes period in which an edit is not considered as a new edit. That is what you don't get the link to the revision page: Because the software didn't create a new revision.
If you edit the post after more than 5 minutes, then you will see the usual link that takes you to the page for the revisions.

Comment: See my question. This is the only place left it seems. Earlier you could see the revision from the post itself.

Comment: I update my answer; nothing changed for me, and I am still able to see the revisions of a post from the post itself.

Comment: Well, even I can see them now. Not sure what's going on. I'm pretty sure this wasn't the case till now for me. I'll keep an eye on it. Also, I'm not smoking /drunk right now ;)

Comment: see my update. That's what threw me off.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was never on for posts that weren't edited or weren't Community Wiki - maybe you had a version of [Stack Exchange modification userscript](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts) which adds a history link to each post.

[image]